# Am I banned after 9 month overstay in Sweden?

Tags: visas, overstaying, sweden

I just want know about the penalties for overstay in Sweden.

I start traveling to Sweden from 2014 using six months residence permit.  I always returned to India before my visa expired. After 3 months, I would apply for another six months permit. This last time I overstayed in Sweden for 9 months.

I was facing some personal problems. That’s only the reason for this long overstay. I decided to go to the Swedish immigration and surrender myself. They said you don’t have the right to stay.

They gave me a form and told me to hand it over to the airport immigration police. Within two days I booked my ticket to India and I handed over that paper to the immigration policeman and he said nothing.

I know I made a big mistake. Have I been banned? And if so, for how long?

Comment: Hi Neha.  This question is hard to read.  Can you please write in complete sentences (capital letter at the beginning, period at the end) and break up your text into paragraphs?

Comment: You can use the "edit" button to make changes to your post.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @mkennedy, it's still not clear as to what the ask is. Banned from what? Do you plan to apply for a visa to go to Sweden or another country.

Comment: @nikhil It's pretty obvious: banned from entering Sweden.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, not obvious to me. It could be a schengen ban as well.

Answer (score 4):

You did a good thing by walking up there *on your own*, and then by *voluntarily leaving the country*. The mere fact that they gave you a paper and let you go to the airport *on your own* probably shows that you are not banned - otherwise they would have forced-transported you directly to the airport.

However, if you apply for a visa again, you will need to convince them this would not happen again. They will ask "*What if you have 'personal problems' again - will you overstay again?*", and it will be hard to convince them that this wouldn't happen again. Unless you have strong arguments, you will probably be declined a further visa.

Comment: Thank you so much I surely convince them I will never do the same thing again no overstay further that for sure

Comment: Donvoted because of the first paragraph. Voluntarily leaving after overstaying has no positive impact on future applications, and drawing an inference on wether there is an accompanying ban is purely speculative. The second paragraph is spot on, it is very likely that the OP will have a hard time securing a schengen visa in the near future.

Comment: @nikhil No idea about Sweden, but the UK's bans are shorter if you left on your own using your own money.